# Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message

Tags: firebase, next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy a NEXT JS app that uses firebase-admin on Vercel.

```js
import * as firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

if (!firebaseAdmin.apps.length) {
  firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert({
      privateKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,

      clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,

      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    }),

    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  });
}
```

When I deploy it to vercel with environment variables as:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

[image: key]

I get this error message.

```js
> Build error occurred
Error: Certificate object must contain a string "private_key" property.
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
    at new Certificate (/vercel/path0/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:118:19)
    at new CertCredential (/vercel/path0/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:187:64)
    at Object.cert (/vercel/path0/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:220:58)
    at Object.3996 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/241.js:115:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/dashboard.js:124:81
    at Function.__webpack_require__.a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:103:13) {
  type: 'FirebaseAppError',
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/invalid-credential',
    message: 'Certificate object must contain a string "private_key" property.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app'
}
Error! Command "npm run build" exited with 1
Error: Command "vercel build" exited with 1
```

However running `npm run build` builds with no error locally.

```
.env.local
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (4/4)
info  - Finalizing page optimization  

Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ / (466 ms)                             461 B           271 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B             270 kB
├ ○ /404 (450 ms)                          526 B           271 kB
├ λ /api/hello                             0 B             270 kB

+ First Load JS shared by all              270 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-a87821de553db91d.js   45 kB
  ├ chunks/main-567f0ec5ceee81fc.js        29.7 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-b443b414c9e8f379.js  195 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-42cdea76c8170223.js     1.07 kB
  └ css/966e875c066cf46b.css               5.18 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

I do not understand how to fix this because this runs locally and builds without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.
`.env.local` can have values like

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

But in vercel environment variables add the keys without the double quotes `""`.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

When you add the keys it should reformat itself and look something like this.
You can `console.log` the values locally, that will look like this below and paste the exact same value in Vercel env.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
your
secret
key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too. Removing the quotes didn't help this far.
However, my comment is related to a different thing: You are setting the private key to a NEXT_PUBLIC var (accessible via front-end, hence, exposed).

Just that. Sorry if it's not relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! I have change them to the env variable

Answer (score 0):

You should **NEVER** use NEXT_PUBLIC_ on a secure credential like **FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY**. It will exposes it to the frontend. If a mistake is make and the key is used in client code. It will open your entire firebase application up to easily be hacked. Change the key to FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY which will only expose it to the backend which is all that's needed for the admin sdk.

@nohorbee already mentioned this. But I believe it's important to add emphasis to importance of making this change.